# C# unit test - How can I mock a local variable which relies on network?

Tags: c#, plc

The method to be tested is just like this

```
public class DataRetrieval : IDataRetrieval
{
    private readonly ILogger<DataRetrieval> _logger;
    public DataRetrieval(ILogger<DataRetrieval> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<PlcResult> RetrievePlcAsync(string ip, int db)
    {
        using var plc = new Plc(CpuType.S71500, ip, 102, 0, 1);
        var data = await plc.ReadClassAsync<PlcResult>(db); // the plc is third dependency
        _logger.LogInformation("Retrieve data from plc: {@Data}", data);
        return data;
    }
}
```

I have setup a simulation environment with TIA for plc, but it causes dependency for unit test. What should I do for this situation?
Can I realize mocking the local variable `Plc`?
Plc is introduced with [S7NETPLUS](https://github.com/S7NetPlus/s7netplus)

---

Edited:
The method to be tested

```
public async Task<PlcResponse> RetrievePlcAsync(string ip, int db)
{
    using var plc = new Plc(CpuType.S71500, ip, 102, 0, 1);
    var data = await plc.ReadClassAsync<PlcResult>(db); // the plc is third dependency
    _logger.LogInformation("Retrieve data from plc: {@Data}", data);
    if (data.Type == 1)
    {
        var order = await _orderRepository.GetByIdAsync(data.OrderId);
        if (order == null)
        {
            return new PlcResponse(ResponseStatus.NotExists);
        }

        return new PlcResponse(ResponseStatus.Exsits, order);
    }
    else
    {
        return new PlcResponse(ResponseStatus.InvalidType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Move creation of your instance into a factory, inject the factory as dependency, call the factory

Comment: Well, if Plc gets mocked, the method won't do anything

Comment: If your SuT creates an object, you can't simply make it create something different. That would imply you had another SuT. However when creation of dependencies happens *outside* your SuT, you can replace those dependencies as you like. Having said this you should inject the object to your SuT in order to mock it.

Comment: @knittl I've tried this. But I realized that if I replace it with another interface, how could I write unit test for the implementation of the interface. It seems to be endless.

Comment: @Paddi you don't write a _unit test_ in that case (for certain definitions of "unit test"). You would require an _integration_ test (connecting to a real PLC server or by writing a dummy PLC server yourself, which can be spun up for your test)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your class' design to be testable. One such approach is the introduction of a factory:

```
interface IPlcFactory {
   Plc Create(string ip);
}

class PlcFactory : IPlcFactory {
   public override Plc Create(string ip) {
     new Plc(CpuType.S71500, ip, 102, 0, 1)
   }
}

public class DataRetrieval : IDataRetrieval
{
    private readonly ILogger<DataRetrieval> _logger;
    private readonly IPlcFactory _plcFactory;
    public DataRetrieval(ILogger<DataRetrieval> logger, IPlcFactory plcFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _plcFactory = plcFactory;
    }

    public async Task<PlcResult> RetrievePlcAsync(string ip, int db)
    {
        using var plc = _plcFactory.Create(ip);
        var data = await plc.ReadClassAsync<PlcResult>(db); // the plc is third dependency
        _logger.LogInformation("Retrieve data from plc: {@Data}", data);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Then you can pass a test double in your test instead of the production implementation.

Note that your method/class isn't doing much, except logging. I wonder how much a unit test will benefit you here.

Comment: I'm sorry that the demo code makes you confused. There area some other steps before and after the demo code, which I'm thinking it does not block the unit test. I'd edit it to be more specific.